# First or second person in url naming

Tags: html, url, naming-conventions, naming

I am creating a web app and I'm not sure how should I name the page that the user uses to set its preferences, I called it `set-my-preferences` but I'm wondering if it should be `set-your-preferences`.

Is there a naming convention for the urls relative to the user?
Should I use first (my) or second (your) person in the url?

PS: I doubt this question has not been asked already but I googled it and looked for it on stackoverflow and could not find anything

Comment: For URL, I would suggest it to be something that's clear and also very short. For your case it can just be `preferences`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using set-my-preferences because it involves the user because they are more focused if a thing is about them. From my personal experience this has worked best for me.